# What is an effective method to get a Django class reference when there are duplicated class names in different modules?

Tags: django

I have a function that takes a class reference to create an SQL string.

I can get the class reference from globals() as long as the class name is unique.

Example call.

```
module_name_a.models.get_insert_string(globals()['DriverShiftPreference'])
```

If there are duplicate class names in different modules then I get collisions.
For example, if there is module_name_a.models.Driver and module_name_b.models.Driver then

```
module_name_a.models.get_insert_string(globals()['Driver'])
```

returns a result from module_name_b.models.Driver.

What is an effective method to get a Django class reference when there are duplicated class names in different modules?

Comment: You can choose one of them and import it with a different name, like `from a_module import driver ----- from b_module import driver as other_driver`. the second will be available with `other_driver` as name

Comment: That would work and there are many class names that collide. I'm looking for a way to have 'globals' but only within a module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a much simpler way. Just pass in the model.

Example.

```
junction.models.get_insert_string(depot_maestro.models.Group)
```

which returns

insert into groups ( "DEPOT_ID","uuid","Notes","Percentage","abn","address","admin_fee","bank_details","bookings_percent","creationAccount","creationTimeStamp","email","fax","group_account_name","group_colour","group_logo","group_logo_2","group_name","group_number","group_service_mark_as_paid","gst","message","meter","modificationAccount","modificationTimeStamp","omit_from_group_reports","parts_at_cost","phone","remit_all_cash","rollover_amount","roster_group","sort_order","vehicle_fk" ) values ( ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,? )'

Answer (score 0):

Found using inspect gets most of the way there.

```
# in a module called junction
import inspect 
def get_insert_string(class_reference):
    fields = []
    arguments = []
    for field in class_reference._meta.fields:
        if field.primary_key:
            pass
        elif field.help_text:
            fields.append('"%s"' % field.help_text)
            arguments.append('?')
    result = 'insert into %s ( %s ) values ( %s )' % ( class_reference.filemaker_table_name, u','.join(fields), u','.join(arguments)) 
    return result 

def make_models_map_from_module(module_):
    result = {}
    for item in inspect.getmembers(module_.models):
        key = item[0]
        value = item[1]
        if key == '__builtins__':
            break
        else:
            result[key] = value
    return result
```

Sample usage:

```
import junction
import depot_maestro
depot_maestro_model_map = junction.models.make_models_map_from_module(depot_maestro)
junction.models.get_insert_string(depot_maestro_model_map['Driver'])
u'insert into driver ( "DEPOT_ID","uuid","ABN_number","account_name","address_1","advance_payment_days","bank_account","barred_flag","biometric_print","bsb","change_log","comm_fixed_percent","company","contract_end_date","contract_fixed","contract_notice_period","contract_start_date","contract_terms","country","date_activated","DOB","default_roster_template_id","EFT_code","email","external_id","fax","first_name","fuel_pin","fuel_split_percent","gender","is_owner","known_as","last_contacted","middle_name","nationality","Next_of_kin","next_of_kin_mobile","Next_of_kin_phone","next_of_kin_relationship","next_of_kin_work","passport","password","pay_in_choice","phone","pref_age","pref_body_type","pref_name_display","pref_transmission","remit_gst_for_ATO_who_remits","roster_template_id","status","surname","toll_serial_no","tsl_owner","unreliable_flag","www_LastKnown_GPS","www_LastKnown_Status","www_LastKnown_Timestamp","creationAccount","creationTimeStamp","modificationAccount","modificationTimeStamp" ) values ( ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,? )'
```